# Change the center of React-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to dynamically change the center of a map-container with data provided externally. I get the data as a string, and then parse it to get it as numbers instead. But when I enter lat to the const center, I get a NaN when trying use it.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useCasparData } from 'caspar-graphics'
import { useTimeline } from '@nxtedition/graphics-kit'
import './style.css'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import './leaflet.css'

export default function Lowerthird () {
  const { text01, text02, text03, text04 } = useCasparData()
  const lat = parseFloat(text01)
  const zoom = 15
  const center = [lat, 13.440222]

  function onLoad(timeline) {
    timeline
      .add('start')
      .from('.name', { x: -2000 }, 'start')
      .from('.titel', { x: -1000 }, 'start')
  }

  function onStop(timeline) {
    timeline
      .reverse()

  }

  //useTimeline(onLoad, onStop)
  

  return (
  <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} zoomControl={false}>
  <TileLayer
    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />
</MapContainer>
    
  )
}

export const previewData = {
  text01: '59.392133',
  text02: '13.440222',
  text03: '15',
  text04: '[59.392133, 13.440222]'
}
```

I have looked through several threads here, but I have not found a answer that solves this for me... I do realize that the map-container is immutable - I just can't seem to figure out how to update it or set a new center...
(Oh... I am a total noob to react/leaflet, I am just trying to find a simple way to use Openstreetmap as a overlay in our broadcasts (tv))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMap()` from a child component.
And with map, you can use functions such as flyTo to move around on the map.

Sadly useMap needs to be used from the child scope of MapContainer, however, you can just create an invisible component and add as a child and provide it with the new position when you want it to move.
So something like this (I have not tested this code but I have done similar stuff with markers):

```js
interface ChangeCenterProps {
  position: { lat: number; lng: number };
}
const ChangeCenter: React.FC<ChangeCenterProps> = ({ position }) => {
  const map = useMap();
  map.flyTo(position);
  return <></>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I did find a similiar solution to yours. BUT my issue still is that I get a NaN error. In my code above, I get my data from an external source, "text01" - but I am not able to get that external data in to the map however. This is when I get NaN... Text01 is parsed so it should be a number...

Comment: `parseFloat()` will return NaN if it cant parse it to a float so its either a string or undefined. You could check that with some cave man debugging and add console.log(text01) before you try to parse it

Comment: hmh... It looks like it can parse it correctly. I did try both looking with console.log(text01) but also with console.log(isNaN(text01)), which returns false. Hmh!